# Sides of a Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I’ll preface this with an apology if the question is too basic, too stupid or too weird.

I was reading Euclid’s definition of a circle - that is, “a circle is a plane figure bounded by one line, called the circumference, and is such that all straight lines drawn from a certain point inside the figure to the circumference are equal to each other.”

I wondered what would happen if the circumference of a circle with radius $r$ were stretched to form a straight line with a distance to the center being $r$, so that if you were to draw a dotted line from the center to either end of the newly formed line, it formed a triangle. My question is: would the length of the side be?

The length of one side would be $2\pi r$, and the height, as it were, would be $r$. How would you go about finding the side?

(Sorry again - this question is keeping me up).

Comment: It would honestly be less confusing if you just asked "If I have an isosceles triangle whose base has length $2\pi r$ and height $r$, what would the length of the two legs be?"

Comment: Is it isosceles? Can we assume the two sides are equal? How do we do so?

Comment: If the triangle isn't isosceles, then I'm even more confused as to what your question is. It would probably be best to draw out a picture of this triangle, because the description is hard to understand.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of your construction is that you first chose a midpoint. Then, draw a circle of radius $r$ about that point. Now, chose an arbitrary point along the circumference of the circle, and draw a line tangent to the circle at the point that is length $2\pi r$, and whose midpoint is the point where the line is tangent to the circle. Finally, draw a line connecting the center of the circle to either end point of the tangent line. What is the length of this line?

Comment: @JacobRaymond not at all a well-writen question and I can understand your frustration

Comment: @TurtleDovePython no math question is ever considered stupid. When you think about it, we today find it stupid the assertion every number must be rational, but some 2000 years ago Hippasus was considered the stupid one! Hope that lightens your mood

Answer (score 1):

To start welcome to SE, I started a few weeks ago so your not alone.

To visualize this, draw a diagram. If the line connecting the center to the line is perpendicular to the line (I assume that's what you are saying) then you have yourself a perpendicular bisector (the line splits it in two $r\pi$ on each side)! To find the length of the side you would use the Pythagorean Theorem ($a^2+b^2=c^2$)Plugging in the values, the side length comes out to be $r^2(1+\pi)$.

Hopes that helps!!

Comment: If the triangle formed is not isosceles the length $l$, has to follow... $r^2(1+\pi)\leq l < r^2(1+4\pi)$